# Video/Article of someone going through a company's balance sheet?

Tags: balance-sheet

I'm basically looking for a (rough) financial analysis of a company. I'd prefer a bank, but if it's an insurance company or a corporate it's fine, too.

I know I can read up on the different positions on a balance sheet and P&L, but I know that for me it's extremely helpful to start off with an example. Someone knowledgeable telling me what they're looking at and why. After that, I can read up on stuff, maybe look at the B/S of the peer group.

My goal isn't to become an expert, but to get a fundamental understanding of the important parts of a company's annual report (obviously this differs depending on the industry, company size, regulatory framework etc.).

If I should post this question somewhere else, just tell me.

Comment: A bank would be a bad example to start with. Banks’ balance sheets are both weird and complicated, compared to most other kinds of company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you look into a bank's Uniform Bank Performance Report (UBPR). It is a much more useful tool to analyze a bank's financial condition and overall health. You can access them at the link below.

https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/ManageFacsimiles.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) has really good video lessons on a huge range of topics. They have a section on [accounting and financial statements](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/core-finance/accounting-and-financial-stateme). Start with the three lessons about cash vs. accrual accounting to see the example he sets up, and then dive in to the balance sheet, income statement, and cash flow statement lessons.